# How to set values from the store in extjs4

Tags: grid, extjs4, store

I have a grid using this store:

```
MyStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore',{
     data   : [
        ['field1'],
        ['field2'],
        ['field3']
    ],
    fields  : [{name:'title'}]
});
```

So i get a grid with 3 rows and 1 column.
I create an event that when i select a row in another grid the content of row 1 in this grid change (for example 'field1' becomes 'field4').

This code makes me get the content of the row: MyStore.data.items[0].data.title
But i don't know how to change it in the grid

I hope my question is clear and thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
MyStore.getAt(0).set('title', 'field4');
```